# Finding a specific file path when two files have the same name in different locations in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to load and save an xml file called `Modules.xml` in my code. I have currently got the file path hardcoded as shown below. I am trying to get the file path within my code without it being hardcoded.

I have tried using `Path.GetDirectoryName` **and** `new FileInfo("Modules.xml").Directory.FullName`. However, both of these target the file in my debug folder, when the file I need is in the main solution folder.

Is there a way to target the file in my main solution folder instead of my debug folder? (both files are called Modules.xml)

```
doc.Save("C:\\Users\\Matthew\\Desktop\\Year4\\Object Oriented\\Project1\\Project1\\Modules.xml");
```

Both file locations are shown below:

```
C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Year4\Object Oriented\Project1\Project1\Modules.xml
```

^^^this is the file path I need for my code^^^

```
C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Year4\Object Oriented\Project1\Project1\bin\Debug\Modules.xml
```

Comment: Sounds a bit XY'ish, why not just copy the file to the output directory by using content and copy if newer, why would you want to taget the solution directory, which will not be delivered with your application

Comment: What happens when you would copy your executable to different folder and run it there? just tick the "copy to output directory" in your xml file in your solution folder, so it will always be there.

Comment: The xml file is on 'copy always' already. However, if i specifically target the debug folder by putting doc.Load("Modules.xml) and doc.Save("Modules.xml) all the data is only saved at runtime and when the program is closed the data is not saved and the data is removed from the xml file.

Comment: Change "Copy always" to "Copy if newer".  You're currently telling it to overwrite the xml file every time you build.  Your approach of using the application directory is correct.

Comment: Thanks, this has fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here would be to use a configuration file, e.g. *app.config*, for storing such a string. Then you can change file path without recompiling the code, and your file can be stored in any location accessible by application.

If you really want to access your file the way you explained, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` will provide you with the *bin/Debug* location in runtime. Then you can find a relative path from there like:

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\", fileName);
```

where fileName is "Modules.xml" for example.

Comment: This doesn't get me to the correct file path, this takes me to C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Year4\Object Oriented\Project1\Project1\bin\Modules.xml however, the file path im trying to get is C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Year4\Object Oriented\Project1\Project1\Modules.xml

Comment: Each "..\" is basically a directory up, so you can also create it yourself.

Comment: I changed my code to this            string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\", "Modules.xml");
            doc.Load(filePath); however, it still targets the xml file in the debug not the main solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you supposed to do with your file, but the filePath should be correct now, you can test it in debug.

Comment: I've checked the filePath variable in debug mode and this is the outcome "C:\\Users\\Matthew\\Desktop\\Year4\\Object Oriented\\Project1\\Project1\\bin\\Debug\\..\\..\\Modules.xml" which is still in the debug file?

Comment: That is the correct path, try using it in your file system directly to check.
As I've already mentioned, ..\ means go one directory above in file system.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using Path.GetDirectoryName and new
>   FileInfo("Modules.xml").Directory.FullName. However, both of these
>   target the file in my debug folder, when the file I need is in the
>   main solution folder.

That's because `bin\Debug` is your working directory when you start and run the project. To change that, you can set the `working directory environment variable` to point to your solution directory (instead of `bin\debug|release`) which I wouldn't recommend that. Because when you finally endup with development, and release the application, there wouldn't be any solution directory that holds your XML file. What I can suggest is to copy your XML file to the output folder. Either you are in development (debug) or production (release) mode, the XML always going to be copied to final directory. And you can access the working directory with something like `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`. To enabling copy XML to output directory, right-click on it, choose Properties, set `Build Action` to `None`, and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always` or `Copy if newer`. You're good to go now.